# Angle of wiring

Tags: pcb, wiring, ipc

I´m relativ new to PCB designing and therefore I have two questions.
I started to design a simple 1-Layer PCB with a circular shape. In the Internet I found that a wire must not be "too long" elsewhere I have to use a wider wire.

1-Question 1:
In my case I have + and - close to each other and then a wire that goes across the entire circle to link them. 
The radius is 20 mm with 100 mA Current, thikness 35µm. Is 0,3 mm for the wire enough?
I used this calculator: http://circuitcalculator.com/wordpress/2006/01/31/pcb-trace-width-calculator/

2-Question 2
When I want to connect a Component, should I go directly or use a 45° ?
I hope the pics can clarify my questions

[image]

I find always IPC-610A Norms but when I google them they cost too much for a student :(

I hope that my questions are clear.
I´ll be happy with any suggestion I get :)

Thank you in Advance

Comment: #2 is better, from a manufacturing point of view. You want to avoid acute angles because of acid traps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) An Electronics technician told me once you should not make a 90° angle after a long wire, in my case I have a circular wire with 70 mm, so there won´t be Problems using Proposition 2?

Comment: The 90° angle is an old myth that keeps staying alive. If it's true, then you can't use a connector, hole mounted components, or a via. Obviously all of this works well even in high speed designs.

Comment: @pipe It is not a myth, it was a real thing and was very critical. Nowadays it's less risky to have 90 degree angles or smaller, but it is still not good practice. There are ways to minimize these 90-degree angles, like teardrops. Many real professionals have been using those since the invention of PCBs to avoid the issues with trapped etchant

Comment: In general, the narrower the trace, the more you need to worry about acid traps. But I definitely recommend you avoid acute angles and use teardrops just so other people don't question/comment on your design. It is easier to add them than explain why you didn't.

Comment: @mkeith I have wires with a width of 0.3mm, is that risky? and for the teardrops I´ll use them when I´ll want to connect the plus to the Pad, like in proposition 2. Thanks for your advice

Comment: As far as real risk goes, I really can't say since I am not an expert in that area. But 0.3mm is a reasonably large trace. As noted above, it is easy to avoid acute angles and add teardrops (you can even ask the board fabricator to do it for you after you generate gerbers).

Answer (score 1):

In regards to question 1, I use this calculator to determine a general recommended trace width: http://www.4pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.html . It is based on IPC2221, which is the international standard for PCB design.

In regards to question 2, definitely use proposition 2. As Lior Bilia mentioned, you should always avoid acute angles as they can act as acid traps, which will cause deterioration over time. If acid is trapped it'll eat away at the copper trace potentially causing issues down the road. Keep it head on, and use the teardrop feature (shortcut T-E) to round off the 90-degree corners where the trace meets the pad. This ensures that no acid can be trapped, and is just good practice.

Comment: Acid traps are no longer a problem, PCB manufacturing technology has moved away from that.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and for the calculator, I think i´m safe with 0.3 mm. For the tear drops I googled itand it seems that it´s used with Drilling so for THT pads. I forget to say that I only have smd components (due to manufacturing price later if I want a sample). So Teard drops is to be used with tht, right?

Comment: @pipe So does it means that I can use configuration 2 without worrying about the length of my wire?

Comment: @pipe You are correct in that PCB manufacturing has come a long way and most do not use acids, but it is still good practice to avoid acute angles nonetheless. Some manufacturers, especially cheap Chinese ones, may still use etchants so it's better to plan for the worst case. It's just good practice.

Comment: @sofiane1925 no, you are not correct. Teardrops can be used on any pads (TH or SMD) as well as where two traces meet in a "T" or where a trace necks down. Here is the dialog from Altium for adding teardrops: http://s27.postimg.org/g55fbvqab/Teardrops.png . I mentioned the shortcuts, but seeing as you're new to Altium I realize you might not know what that is. Pressing "T-E" is equivalent to opening the "Tools" menu and selecting "Teardrops". Whenever you see an underlined letter in a menu title or menu item name, you can simply type the underlined letter and it will select that item.

Comment: @destrom8 Thank you bro really for the trick :D You got it right I´m new with Altium Designer but I´m struggling with what I can. So your advice helped me to worry less about the Pad, only thing left is the wire, and if what I did is correct or I may have later electrical Problems. I hope this pic can show it better. https://picload.org/image/wwdwrca/unbenannt.png

Comment: @sofiane1925 Altium is a very tricky program to get the hang of. It has a very steep learning curve, but once you get the feel for it you will really begin to love it. Anyway, in order to get teardrops in tight areas (as shown in your screenshot) you'll need to reduce the teardrop radius in the "T-Junction" section. It's possible Altium doesn't recognize it as a "T" because the long side is actually round. Do you absolutely need rounded traces? Generally I try to stick to straight traces, personally.

Comment: @derstrom8 Well as Isaid at my first post, this is a circular PCB ( Actually in the form of a disc). Another mechanic Student will desidn the "Host" so I have to stick with a circular wire, or a bunch of bows ( I see it in some designs so actually I´m wondering if it will be better than a complete cicrle, electrically speaking) something like this may be:    https://picload.org/view/wwdwawc/unbenannt2.png.html

Answer (score 0):

The choice between both prepositions depends on what kind of trace this is and whether or not you intend to etch the board yourself or have it manufactured. If it's a simple DC line, with no particularly sensitive signal and you use a board manufacturer: GO nuts, angles don't matter that much.

If you're dealing with any kind of digital signals or any RF stuff, you have to keep in mind that what you drew is essentially a stub. If that's a foreign term to you: stubs are like discontinuities in your trace impedance, if you'd have to translate it to water in a tube, what you're doing is making the water go around a sharp bend, which creates turbulence. You probably already know this "electrical turbulence", just look at all the ripple and ringing on your typical scope trace.

General rule of thumb when you lay out your traces: imagine you're laying out pipes which carry water and you want as little turbulence as possible. There's a BUNCH of scenario's the turbulence won't make any difference, but it's a nice way to think. A great signal integrity expert once said: BE the signal!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I deal with normal DC signals, two Condensators in parallel and bunch of resistors and other basic components. Like I said basic PCB with no RF or something that must keep its Integrity (Thank God). Just Voltage and current that must be delivered to all components. Only thing the Plus goes across the circle, and everytime I must have a 90° to connect components. That´s what I feared, to have electrical Problems after a while (heat or Stress ...). My PCB must run for two weeks in the Lab to be validated so I can´t really pass of contraints.  I hope it´s clear

Comment: I don't exactly understand why you need a 90° to connect your components? But anyway, I think you're fine either way. If it's your first realy PCB and you haven't bitten off more than you can obviously chew, you can get away with a crapload of bad practises. 

About the validation: will the environment be particularly hot? If not, refer to what I've said before: you can get away with A LOT.

Comment: I don´t need 90°, I only want to have a fluid circulation of current, like you described it with pipes and water. For the environment I have no idea. The idea is to conceive a PCB Board that works under "all" circumstances, and not only a specific one.

Comment: A PCB that works under all possible circumstances is not really possible. You can make something that will be great for hot environments, you can make something that will work on the north pole or you can simply make something for room temperature(however arbitrarily you may define that). When designing without specific constraints: try to follow best practises, the moment you hit a problem (size constraints or what have you), most of the time you can make the trade off and go for whatever is practical.

Best practise in your case is option number 2, because you are making a 90° bend anyway.